# Dynamically update Tkinter Button Colour

Tags: python, tkinter

I am currently trying to have my program change the colour of a Tkinter button.

I have the buttons stored in a list, and when the update method for the buttons is called, it is suppose to reset all the buttons, and then set the value of the passed button to green.  Here is some code that works as an example of what I am trying to do:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def updateButton(value):
    for btn in btnList:
        btnList[btn].configure(bg = "white")
    btnList[value].configure(bg = "green")

root = tk.Tk()

btn1 = ttk.Button(root, text = "BTN 1", command = lambda: updateButton("BTN 1"))
btn1.pack()
btn2 = ttk.Button(root, text = "BTN 2", command = lambda: updateButton("BTN 2"))
btn2.pack()

btnList = { "BTN 1" : btn1, "BTN 2" : btn2 }

root.mainloop()
```

The problem I am having is that when I attempt to run the `updateButton` method, I get the following error:

```
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-bg"
```

I have tried changing `bg` to `background` and still get the same error.  What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You are using buttons from ttk, not tkinter. Like the error says, ttk buttons don't have a `background` option.

Comment: @BryanOakley Ahh....so I suppose my options would then be to use tk Buttons instead of ttk ones.  Is there a way to change the background of a ttk Button outside of creating a style for every button?

Comment: I don't think there is. That's the whole point of ttk, to use themes instead of individual configuration options.

Comment: @BryanOakley okay thank you.  I suppose I will just switch over to using tk Buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bryan Oakley said, ttk buttons don't have a background option, the only way to change their background is to use a style:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

def updateButton(value):
    for btn in btnList:
        btnList[btn].configure(style='white.TButton')
    btnList[value].configure(style='green.TButton')

root = tk.Tk()

style = ttk.Style(root)
style.configure('white.TButton', background='white')
style.configure('green.TButton', background='green')

btn1 = ttk.Button(root, text="BTN 1", command=lambda: updateButton("BTN 1"), 
                  style='white.TButton')
btn1.pack()
btn2 = ttk.Button(root, text="BTN 2", command=lambda: updateButton("BTN 2"), 
                  style='white.TButton')
btn2.pack()

btnList = { "BTN 1" : btn1, "BTN 2" : btn2 }

root.mainloop()
```

Or, as the OP suggested, just switch to tk buttons that have a background option.